# apply() is slow - how to make it faster or what are my alternatives?

Tags: r, apply, r-faq

I have a quite large data frame, about 10 millions of rows. It has columns `x` and `y`, and what I want is to compute

```
hypot <- function(x) {sqrt(x[1]^2 + x[2]^2)}
```

for each row. Using `apply` it would take a lot of time (about 5 minutes, interpolating from lower sizes) and memory.

But it seems to be too much for me, so I've tried different things:

- compiling the `hypot` function reduces the time by about 10%
- using functions from `plyr` greatly increases the running time.

What's the fastest way to do this thing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What about `with(my_data,sqrt(x^2+y^2))` ?

```
set.seed(101)
d <- data.frame(x=runif(1e5),y=runif(1e5))

library(rbenchmark)
```

Two different per-line functions, one taking advantage of vectorization:

```
hypot <- function(x) sqrt(x[1]^2+x[2]^2)
hypot2 <- function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2))
```

Try compiling these too:

```
library(compiler)
chypot <- cmpfun(hypot)
chypot2 <- cmpfun(hypot2)

benchmark(sqrt(d[,1]^2+d[,2]^2),
          with(d,sqrt(x^2+y^2)),
          apply(d,1,hypot),
          apply(d,1,hypot2),
          apply(d,1,chypot),
          apply(d,1,chypot2),
          replications=50)
```

Results:

```
                       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
5       apply(d, 1, chypot)           50  61.147  244.588    60.480    0.172
6      apply(d, 1, chypot2)           50  33.971  135.884    33.658    0.172
3        apply(d, 1, hypot)           50  63.920  255.680    63.308    0.364
4       apply(d, 1, hypot2)           50  36.657  146.628    36.218    0.260
1 sqrt(d[, 1]^2 + d[, 2]^2)           50   0.265    1.060     0.124    0.144
2  with(d, sqrt(x^2 + y^2))           50   0.250    1.000     0.100    0.144
```

As expected the `with()` solution and the column-indexing solution à la Tyler Rinker are essentially identical; `hypot2` is twice as fast as the original `hypot` (but still about 150 times slower than the vectorized solutions).  As already pointed out by the OP, compilation doesn't help very much.

Comment: Thanks, that worked instantly! I'm new to R, still can't get used that all the operators are vectorized.

Comment: Vectors are a beautiful thing :)

Comment: +1 for benchmarking!   interesting that `[` is slower than `with`.  `$` would get you even faster results!

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, I think that's just noise -- the timing difference is about 0.007 seconds ...

Comment: @BenBolker.  I was curious so I ran this 100x 250reps:  `with` and `$` were each faster ~45% of the time, `[` only about 10%.

Comment: If `m <- as.matrix(d)`, then `sqrt((m * m) %*% c(1, 1))` is competitive (probably ~1% faster, which means ~nothing).

Comment: None of the benchmarking solutions assign the result! Are we trying to add a column to `d` or create a new vector in the parent environment?

Comment: @mnel: the OP doesn't seem to say (it just says "I want to compute ..."), so I guess it's left open to interpretation.

Comment: I hope they won't be computing to display the 10 million rows in the console window. Where they make the assignment will be important.

Comment: Hmm.  Based on a quick trial `r <- numeric(1e8)` it takes about 4-8 seconds to allocate/assign a vector of the relevant size. If the example above scales linearly it will take about 250 seconds to do the computation; are we worrying prematurely about optimization?  It's also not clear whether temporary memory utilization is a problem or not (`object.size` of the vector I made above is 760Mb).  We've already gotten the OP a speedup of about 250x from their original solution ... it's not clear where the priority should be after that ...

Comment: I think the memory issues (conversion within apply) is important here too.

Comment: @chersanya: I laughed when I saw your first comment above, as after using R for a while now, I can't get used to that other languages aren't vectorized.  Every time I need to now, I think to myself "really, I have to write this loop myself?"

Answer (score 14):

While Ben Bolkers answer is comprehensive, I will explain other reasons to avoid `apply` on data.frames.

`apply` will convert your `data.frame` to a matrix. This will create a copy (waste of time and memory), as well as perhaps causing unintended type conversions.

Given that you have 10 million rows of data, I would suggest you look at the `data.table` package that will let you do things efficiently in terms of memory and time.

---

For example, using `tracemem`

```
x <- apply(d,1, hypot2)
tracemem[0x2f2f4410 -> 0x2f31b8b8]: as.matrix.data.frame as.matrix apply
```

This is even worse if you then assign to a column in `d`

```
d$x <- apply(d,1, hypot2)
tracemem[0x2f2f4410 -> 0x2ee71cb8]: as.matrix.data.frame as.matrix apply 
tracemem[0x2f2f4410 -> 0x2fa9c878]: 
tracemem[0x2fa9c878 -> 0x2fa9c3d8]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
tracemem[0x2fa9c3d8 -> 0x2fa9c1b8]: $<-.data.frame $<-
```

4 copies! -- with 10 million rows, that will probably come and bite you at somepoint.

If we use `with`, there is no `copying` involved, if we assign to a vector

```
y <- with(d, sqrt(x^2 + y^2))
```

But there will be if we assign to a column in the data.frame `d`

```
d$y <- with(d, sqrt(x^2 + y^2))
tracemem[0x2fa9c1b8 -> 0x2faa00d8]: 
tracemem[0x2faa00d8 -> 0x2faa0f48]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
tracemem[0x2faa0f48 -> 0x2faa0d08]: $<-.data.frame $<-
```

Now, if you use `data.table` and `:=` to assign by reference (no copying)

```
 library(data.table)
 DT <- data.table(d)



tracemem(DT)
[1] "<0x2d67a9a0>"
DT[,y := sqrt(x^2 + y^2)]
```

No copies!

---

Perhaps I will be corrected here, but another memory issue to consider is that `sqrt(x^2+y^2))` will create  4 temporary variables (internally)  `x^2`, `y^2`, `x^2 + y^2` and then `sqrt(x^2 + y^2))`

The following will be slower, but only involve two variables being created.

```
 DT[, rowid := .I] # previous option: DT[, rowid := seq_len(nrow(DT))]
 DT[, y2 := sqrt(x^2 + y^2), by = rowid]
```

Answer (score 4):

R is vectorised, so you could use the following, plugging in your own matrix of course

```
X = t(matrix(1:4, 2, 2))^2
>      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    4
 [2,]    9   16

rowSums(X)^0.5
```

Nice and efficient :)